# Unable to change app icon

Tags: android, icons, launch, android-launcher

I am trying to change the launch icon of my already developed android app. I right click on res folder. Go to new --> image asset and change the path given there.

It confirms me that some files will be updated and so on. But my launch icon doesnt change.

On top of that , when I go back to res --> new --> image asset, path has changed itself back to original path:

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png

The above path is not even a part of my project. I am unable to fiure out , where this is hard coded. Please help.

Comment: Hello! did my answer help you? do you mind marking my answer as correct? :)

Answer (score 1):

you can change change an icon, just long press on an app, and this pop-up menu shows up. Tap on Edit. Next, tap on the original icon seen on the left. You can choose a new icon from a pack, or you can create one from the images in your gallery.
You can change icon by installing a custom launcher,

Comment: I think the question was about changing the icon of the App prior to uploading it to the PlayStore for all user, not just for himself on the phone.

Comment: yea Fabian thats true. I am looking to change app icon ...prior o uploading it on google playstore.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your apps AndroidManifest.xml file and change android:icon attribute with your icon

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/your_icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made it like this in my app:

1. delete every single file in your project called ic_launcher.png
   (mostly found in android studio under project->src->res->drawable/mipmap...)
2. rename your own Icon png to: ic_launcher.png
3. drag and drop your icon into the folder 'mipmap' or 'drawable', depending where the file previously was, in your android studio project.  [image: to the red arrow]

done :)

Comment: I tried changing android manifest but nothing happens. default android launcher keeps coming.It is taking ic_launcher.png from the path i mentioned in my question above. and copig fies to that path doesnt seem like a god practice!

Comment: Edited my answer. 
make a security copy from your project and try my method. If It messes up your project, you have the copy. tell me what you ge

Answer (score 1):

On Android Studio, a right click on the root folder of your app > New > Image Asset > Launcher Icons and setting your new icon should do the trick and overwrite the existing one.

If it doesn't, try removing the asset in your project tree first, and try again. [You have to delete every resolution of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7I16.png)!

Answer (score 1):

You should add the new icon in all mipmap folders like xxxhdpi,xxhdpi,xhdpi

Answer (score 1):

Firstly add all the application Icon size in mipmap like mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi.After then just place name in android:icon attribute.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```